# Yii login not working after deploying remotely

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies, yii

I'm trying to set up authentication for a Yii application that I'm building. I started from the demo application and made some changes for style, content, and the forgot password/email confirmation schemes I want to use.

This works locally. The problem is, when I push to the server, I am unable to log in. I know that the call to login() which is made after authenticating the user and stores session or cookies, depending on how main.php is configured, completes successfully. Before the user is redirected, they are logged in. However, this does not persist across the page redirect, e.g. $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl)

The actionLogout() method is never being called, and I've tried both enabling and disabling cookie-based authentication with no change in the behavior of the application.

Because it works locally, I am pretty certain that the problem is with my server configuration. But I can't see it, because my phpinfo is showing that sessions are enabled.

Does anyone have an idea about what the issue might be here? I'm going to attach main.php, SiteController.php, and the output of phpinfo.

main.php - http://pastebin.com/LR4i6vYZ

SiteController.php - http://pastebin.com/Fgm1a1nV

phpinfo - http://pastebin.com/CDE2WqvK

Comment: This issue is solved. I changed the cookie TTL value from 0, which is supposed to make the cookie last indefinitely, to a large numerical value. This shouldn't have worked, but it did. I'm going to file a bug report with Yii. I hope this post helps someone else with the same problem.

Comment: You should not set session cookie to some time, it should expire when user close browser window. For persistent login use "Remember me" feature.

Comment: You're right, of course, but that requires setting the TTL to 0. Which wasn't working. Which is why I asked this question.

Comment: Ok, as far as I remember i didn't have to set coookie TTL. Where do you set TTL, you mean php.ini setting?

Comment: Hi PeterM, sorry for not getting back to you, I didn't see your response. I edited the cookie TTL in main.php.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this exact same issue and have found the cause of the problem (at least in my instance). As mentioned above setting the TTL value for the cookie is not a good idea as this is basically equivalent of forcing "remember me" but the user doesn't know you've done it - not secure.

The problem I came across is that while the log-in worked fine locally when deployed to the live server it only worked if "remember me" was set, this essentially switches Yii over to cookie based auth rather than session based (as you get when not choosing "remember me").

The issue was that on my remote server Yii was unable to write to the default PHP session path (it was able to do so on my local machine but on the remote server the user account was naturally much more locked down then that).

I fixed the problem by creating a session folder outside of the web root and then setting this as the savepath for the session in the yii config file.

protected>>config>>main.php

```
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'session' => array (
        'savePath' => 'pathToSessionsFolder',
    ),
    ...
),
```

Yii should now be able to write the session information correctly. The cookie with the session id was always set correctly on the client but now Yii should be able to match that to the session info written on the server where before it couldn't save it.

An alternate solution to this would be to turn on session management via the database in your Yii settings in the same way (Yii should create the table if it doesn't exist).

```
'session' => array (
    'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
    'connectionID' => 'db',
    'sessionTableName' => 'table_name',
),
```

Comment: Is one method preferred over the other? I went with saving session info to the database as I didn't need to give apache write permissions to the directory. I'm guessing the DB method will likely be a little slower?